# How to add fade in/out on state transition

Tags: flutter, dart

By default, when there's a state change on a `StatefulWidget`, there's no animation on state transition. Is there any way to had some? For example, on transition, I want to fade out the old state and fade in the new state.

I know how to add transition animation between routes, but couldn't find a way to do it between state transitions.

Has an example, let's use the Flutter default app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

So, each time I click the button the number changes immediately. What I would like to see is the old number fade out and the new number fade in.

Comment: see `AnimatedSwitcher` or / and `*Transition` widgets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56724472/5082718), using `AnimatedOpacity` works ok. But I found using `AnimatedSwitcher` much simpler and cleaner.

```dart
(...)
    body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'You have pushed the button this many times:',
          ),
          AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
              return FadeTransition(child: child, opacity: animation);
            },
            child: Text(
              '$_counter',
              key: ValueKey<int>(_counter),
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
(...)
```

See [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) for more information about `AnimatedSwitcher`.

Comment: Thanks but not working. AnimatedSwitcher(duration:constDuration(milliseconds:500),transitionBuilder:(Widgetchild,Animation<double>animation){returnFadeTransition(child:child,opacity:animation);},child:Icon(Icons.mic,size:24.0,color:Colors.red,),),

Answer (score 3):

It will depends how you can manage this, it could be using an animationController and workin with the values of an opacity widgets you will need to add the Mixin  `with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` so the Animation works.

That is one of the wait you could do it but also if you just want an fadeout fadein you can work with an AnimatedOpacity.

Like this:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  double _opacity = 1;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() => _opacity = 0);
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500),() =>
      setState(() {
        _counter++;
        _opacity = 1;
      }
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: _opacity,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              child: Text(
                '$_counter',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is a easy way to do a fadeOur/FadeIn as i said if you need a complete animation and more control in it, definitely you should use an AnimationController.

Comment: where did you add "SingleTickerProviderStateMixin" in your example?

Comment: In the example I'm not using an animation Controller it does not need it, if you need one need to add in your class state like this `class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` but the example code above does not need it.